# How do i optimise memory usage

Tags: php

I'm making use of a flat file (600KB) in my current project (As it's the only fit for the project. And also It won't get to 1MB before it resets)

The file contains arrays of datas in the form:

```
{"/classes.my":{
  "data" : "FIRST-CLASS||SS_3_SCIENCE-B||SS3_SCIENCE_A||SS3_SCIENCE||SS3||"
 }
,

"/ss_3_science-b/created_on.my":{ 
 "data" : "29-08-2019"  }
 }
```

I'm using  `file_get_contents()` to fetch the file

```
function DATABASE__(){

$db__=file_get_contents('file.db'); 

 return json_decode($db__, true);
}
```

If i did not call the function, my page memory usage is less than 400KB, but immediately i call the function, there is hike in  Memory usage- 2.55MB.
If i did not return the `json_decode($db__,true)`  , the memory is 944.81KB

Am i doing something wrong, is 3MB memory usage okay? I'm worried, if later on after completion of the project it reaches 4MB, is it still ok?

Comment: What does the file have?

Comment: @vivek_23 objects so i use json_decode after file_get_contents()

Comment: Ok, so the json is stored which you showed, but why store that json? What is the purpose of it? If it's so necessary and cannot be replaced, the script will take that much memory anyway.

Comment: storing in `$db__` takes memory too, test with piping `json_decode(file_get_contents('file.db'), true)`

Comment: But can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @lawrence thank you, i will try that